# Why are spot channels not exported to video in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

This is one of those obscure questions, but I had built an animation in Photoshop and I'm using a spot channel. When I "export to video" it loses the color that I had specified:

Here's my example:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spot color is a **print** technology. The spot channels are used to designate a specific ink mix.

It has no business in video (which is 100% RGB) and it's not surprising that they are completely ignored.

You can easily merge the Spot Channels with the other channels by highlighting it and choosing "Merge spot channel" from the Channels Panel.

Comment: Dang. That's creative thinking, Johannes, despite the fact it was never going to work. That kind of wacky mistake is how we all learn a lot of our technique. I've made my share... :)